# XSL to CSV - Write at a position

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I need to output some elements to csv from xml. 
My problem is I have search criteria with which i have retrieve an element
Example - I have select every node from nodes list and get the node ID. 
This node ID shall be referred in some other place as nodeIDRef. I have to identify that child Node and get that ID and identify the combination of Node ID and child node ID in another element say

Once I fetch info i will output some values from info, some values from child node and some values from parent node in random order as requested.

Please find examples below

```
enter code here

 <v4:InfoList timestamp="2017-04-03T04:10:11.798Z" xmlns:v4="someNameSpace">
<v4:SList>
    <v4:TAG1Id>
        Content1
    </v4:TAG1Id>
    <v4:TAG2>81d2</v4:TAG2>
    <v4:TAG3>0</v4:TAG3>
</v4:SList>

<v4:VList>
    <v4:TAG1RefId>
        Content1
    </v4:TAG1RefId>
    <v4:VTAG2Id>Material1</v4:VTAG2Id>
    <v4:VTAG3>/path/val</v4:VTAG3>
</v4:VList>

<v4:ZList>
    <v4:TAG1RefId>
        Content1
    </v4:TAG1RefId>
    <v4:VTAG2IdRef>Material1</v4:VTAG2IdRef>
    <v4:value1> ABC</v4:value1>
    <v4:vaue2> DEF </v4:vaue2>
    <v4:value3> GHI</v4:value3>

</v4:ZList>
```

```
ZValue1 ZValue2 VListTag3   SListTag3  Vtag2Id         STag2        Tag1Id        ZValue3
ABC     DEF     /path/val      0         Material1      81d       Content1         GHI
```

Note Column names are not same as element names in xml. 
How can i write to a particular position so that i need not to store the value in memory ?

Comment: Your question is too vague, IMHO.